# accessing second form listbox from first form in vb

Tags: vb.net

how can i getting data from listbox in second form named listform while i am at first form

i have search it a lot on google but not find any usefull ans...

Comment: have you tried searching before asking these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see these questions all the time

Create two forms one called form1 the other from2 drop a button on form 1 and a list box on from two use the defalut names for everything and put this code in your button click handler.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New Form2()
    f.Show()
    f.ListBox1.Items.Add("Added somthing")
   End Sub
```